# block copy paste in Xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to block copy paste from entry. I have tried every solution but it fails in Android 8.1. It works well when user is in potrait mode but after moving in landscape mode cut copy paste menu working properly.
I have used these solutions

1)  Control.LongClickable = false;

2)

```
class Callback : Java.Lang.Object, ActionMode.ICallback
{

    public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, IMenuItem item)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {

    }

    public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what is happening here is that the Android OS presents a full screen editor view for an EditText (the native control type) when in landscape, replacing the page UI, so the properties applied to the control do not affect this new full screen entry UI. The best solution may be to disable the EditText control from using the extracted UI.

So, in addition to what you have already done in 1) 1n 2), add the following:

```
Control.ImeOptions =  Control.ImeOptions | (ImeAction)Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeFlags.NoExtractUi;
Control.SetTextIsSelectable(false); // disallow even selecting the text
```

Now when you move to landscape, the page UI will remain rather than being switched to the full screen EditText UI.